# Import Product Images with external Image URL

Tags: magento2, import

I have URLs of all product images. I want to import it into the new store. I have already added URL(www.demo.com/a.png) in the CSV for every product images. Now I want to know that what to enter in Image File Directory field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Magento 2 you can use external URL into CSV.

So you can use add url with www.

Image File Directory : keep it default one.
It will copy into pub/media/catalog/product.

Comment: Sunil , how can i able to import image from external url ?

Comment: @sunil, if you share any URL means that will help us much more

Comment: @senthil any image url you can use

Comment: @SunilPatel is there any possibility that magento do not copy all the images from external url to it's own directory that is pub/media/catalog/product. As I am storing my images on S3 so I don't want to take the space on my server for the images.

Comment: yes possible, you can assign s3 url into media path