# Magento 2: is there any way to assign product image from remote image url programmatically?

Tags: magento2, product-images

I just want to assign product image from remote image url.

One more thing is i can't able to download image in my server because total size of image is : over 1TB

my code is below :

```
$imageUrl = 'Product image remote url';

$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imageUrl, array('image','small_image','thumbnail','swatch_image'), false, false); 
$product->save();
```

using this code i getting "The image does not exist." error.

Answer (score 0):

Check below links

[Link 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106556/how-to-display-product-image-in-sales-order-view-page/138348)

[Link 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183721/import-product-images-with-external-image-url)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178915/magento2-get-product-images-externally)

these should help!